# Adding items into listview dynamically

Tags: android, android-listview

### Adding items into listview dynamically

I have a list with 2 items.. it is inflated. Now when i add another item dynamically. List view instead of expanding, the third item will be in scroll(only half visible).I have given list view as wrap_content(it must be wrap_content).Is there any way for the list view to expand as all 3 items are visible.pls help..